# Streaming multiple OGG simultaneously in Android

Tags: android, opensl

I need to be able to play two or more (let's say, up to 5) short ogg files simultaneously. And by simultaneously I mean in perfect synchrony. I am able to load them to SoundPool and play, but this sometimes creates a noticeable difference in playback start time, which I want to get rid of.

From my understanding this can be avoided if mixing PCMs into one buffer and playing. But OGG's are not PCMs and need to be somehow efficiently decoded before playing and latency must be very low, ideally as soon as user presses the button. So I figured I need a way to stream OGG into PCM and as I receive buffers I would mix them and feed to AudioTrack. My requirement is Android 2.3.3+, so I cannot use any new codecs provided in Jelly Bean.

Also although OGGs themselves are small, there is a lot of them. So keeping them all decoded in memory (SoundPool or some pre-decoding) may case problems too.

Can someone give me a tip where to dig? Can OpenSL ES do that for me? Or should I think about integrating ffmpeg? And is it even possible to stream simultaneus files with low latency?

Thanks

Comment: Be aware of the inherent inability of Android (before 4.2) of producing low latency audio.

Comment: That kinda sounds depressing

Comment: Yeah, there already have been many discussions about Android and low latency audio. 4.2 gave a big boost to it, but it still could be better.

Answer (score 1):

You can play sounds using AssetPlayers,  but this sometimes creates a noticeable difference in playback start time, yeh...

So, i recomend to decode ogg using Ogg Vorbis (like [here](https://github.com/Suvitruf/Android-ndk/blob/master/AndroidNDK-OpenAL/jni/openaltest/utils/OALOgg.cpp)) and then using this PCM buffer for BufferPlayer.

Btw, check this OpenSL ES wrappers

https://github.com/Suvitruf/Android-ndk/tree/master/OpenSLES